# Sparql query not working

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, virtuoso, linked-data

I try the following SPARQL query on the end point, but it tells me

> Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 4: syntax error at 'UNION' before 'select'

```
select ?uri, ?label where { quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap { graph ?g { ?uri ?p ?label.FILTER (?label = 'biomass'@en) .}. values ?g {<BEFDATA>}}}
UNION
 select ?uri, ?label where { quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap { graph ?g { ?uri ?p ? label.FILTER (?label = 'biomass'@en) .}. values ?g {<COPY>}}}
```

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe you have a syntax error at 'UNION' before 'select'. Did you bother to balance your braces?

Comment: @torazaburo It's not even that;  it's that `union` doesn't combine multiple `select`s, but rather combines triple patterns within a `select`.

Answer (score 3):

On **what** endpoint are you running this?  That makes a big difference.   There are lots of things that aren't legal SPARQL in your query (though they might be accepted by a Virtuoso endpoint).  For instance: (i) it uses undefined prefixes; (ii) you have commas between the projection variables (`?uri, ?label`); (iii) `quad map ...` isn't part of SPARQL syntax; etc.

The main problem, though, that you're getting an error message about, is that `union` should appear between some triple patterns, not between two queries.  E.g., you could do:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?person ?name where {
  { ?person :firstName ?name }
  union 
  { ?person :lastName ?name }
}
```

but you wouldn't do

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?person ?name where { ?person :firstName ?name }
union 
select ?person ?name where { ?person :lastName ?name }
```